# Show a div after a click with native map - ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

Currently I have been developing an application with ionic 3,
In the application I have several market, what I want is that when I click on one I have to show a div that when initializing the app is hidden.
he has been arming in this way but it does not work.

```
<ion-content>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div (click)="viaje();" *ngIf="buttonClicked" class="detalle_chofer">
        <div class="tiempo_llegada">
            <p class="llegada">LLEGANDO EN 2 MIN</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img class="chofer" src="assets/imgs/chofer.png" alt="">
            <p class="nombre_chofer">IVAN JOEL MORE FLORES</p>
            <a class="estrellas" *ngFor="let r of ratingArr">
                <ion-icon name="{{r.icon}}" item-left>
                </ion-icon>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="detalle_auto">
            <img class="auto" src="assets/imgs/auto.png" alt="">
            <p class="color_auto">TOYOTA</p>
            <p class="placa">ABC - 123</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

is css :

```
.detalle_chofer {
        position: absolute;
        background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        width: 100%;
        height: 30%;
        top: 80%;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

TS:

```
public buttonClicked: boolean = false; //Whatever you want to initialise it asç

 addMarker(options) {
    let markerOptions: MarkerOptions = {
      position: new LatLng(options.position.latitude, options.position.longitude),
      title: options.title,
      icon: options.icon
    };
    this.map.addMarker(markerOptions).then(marker => {
      marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK)
        .subscribe(() => {
          var mFound = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(marker._objectInstance)
            .find(e => e.toString() === "Symbol(vars)");
          var title = marker._objectInstance[mFound].title;
          alert(title);
          this.buttonClicked = !this.buttonClicked; //
          console.log(this.buttonClicked);
        });
    });
  }
```

> In this image I put the div in true to be able to visualize it

[image]

Comment: is `console.log(this.buttonClicked);` getting called?

Comment: is true, help me please :c